How to run scipy.optimize.minimize with L-BFGS-B for maxiter (completely)?
I want to run the below code for maxiter = 20001. I don't want it to be stopped by some default criteria.
results = scipy.optimize.minimize(
    fun=get_loss_and_grads,
    x0=params,
    jac=True,
    method='L-BFGS-B',
    options={'maxiter': 20001, 'disp': True, 'ftol': 0.0, 'gtol': 0.0, 'maxcor': 50},
    callback=PrintLossCallback(print_freq=100)
)

Currently, it is stopped at approx. 2500 iterations, but I want it to run for a full 20001 iterations. How do I do that? Below is the full code:
def get_loss_and_grads(params):
    shapes = [w.shape for w in model.get_weights()]
    split_params = np.split(params, np.cumsum([np.prod(shape) for shape in shapes[:-1]]))
    weights = [tf.Variable(param.reshape(shape)) for param, shape in zip(split_params, shapes)]
    model.set_weights(weights)

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = combined_loss(X_train_tf[:, 0:1], X_train_tf[:, 1:2], x_init_tf, t_init_tf, u_initial_tf, x_bc_tf, t_bc_tf)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)

    flattened_gradients = np.concatenate([grad.numpy().flatten() for grad in gradients])
    return loss.numpy().astype(np.float64), flattened_gradients

X_train_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_train.astype(np.float32))
x_init_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_init.astype(np.float32))
t_init_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(t_init.astype(np.float32))
u_initial_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(u_initial.astype(np.float32))
x_bc_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_bc.astype(np.float32))
t_bc_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(t_bc.astype(np.float32))


shapes = [w.shape for w in model.get_weights()]
params = np.concatenate([w.flatten() for w in model.get_weights()])

class PrintLossCallback:
    def __init__(self, print_freq=100):
        self.print_freq = print_freq
        self.iteration = 0

    def __call__(self, xk):
        self.iteration += 1
        if self.iteration % self.print_freq == 0:
            loss, _ = get_loss_and_grads(xk)
            print(f"Iteration {self.iteration}, Loss: {loss}")

start_time = time.time()


results = scipy.optimize.minimize(
    fun=get_loss_and_grads,
    x0=params,
    jac=True,
    method='L-BFGS-B',
    options={'maxiter': 20001, 'disp': True, 'ftol': 0.0, 'gtol': 0.0, 'maxcor': 50},
    callback=PrintLossCallback(print_freq=100)
)

optimized_params = results.x
split_params = np.split(optimized_params, np.cumsum([np.prod(shape) for shape in shapes[:-1]]))
model.set_weights([param.reshape(shape) for param, shape in zip(split_params, shapes)])

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
elapsed_minutes = elapsed_time / 60.0  # Convert seconds to minutes

print(f"Execution time: {elapsed_minutes:.2f} minutes")


Thank you in advance.
Best,
Saif Ur Rehman.
I tried to set 'ftol': 0.0, 'gtol': 0.0, and maxiter to a large number like 200001, but all in vain.

L-BFGS-B can stop for multiple different reasons besides the running out of iterations. Can you post the output of print(results)? I'm particularly interested in the message parameter, which shows why optimization stopped.

The results. success gives True and results.message gives CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH. Please check this post on Stack Exchange where multiple users have replied to this same query of mine.
